# Is there any limitation for the number of (sub) Wallet?

Tags: wallets, accounts, coinbase

Is there a limitation for the number of wallet generated from Etherbase?

Thank you in advance for cooperation!

Comment: Short answer is 'no'. For more details see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/87