# How do you configure geth to use coinbase?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm a novice.  I'm looking for instructions on how to configure geth so it sends my mined eth to coinbase.

In my head, I think the process is:

1. Sync the blockchain

   `geth --datadir /data/ethData --autodag --verbosity 1`
2. wait for it to finish.   Get an ETH address from https://www.coinbase.com/addresses 

   `geth --etherbase '0xa4d8e9cae4d04b093aac82e6cd355b6b963fb7ff' --mine`
3. Profit!

Is that correct?

Answer (score 14):

here's what I do on my private Ethereum Testnets (you don't need to create your own network though):

1. Starting the geth node and entering the JS Console

   ```
   geth --networkid XXXX console
   ```
2. Creating an account. You'll be asked to provide a passphrase.

   ```
   personal.newAccount()
   ```
3. Defining your initial/primary account as coinbase:

   ```
   miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])
   ```
4. Verify coinbase:

   ```
   eth.coinbase
   ```

After that's done you can either exit the JS Console or start the mining process by:

```
miner.start()
```

In case DAG wasn't created, it should automatically be created.

I hope this helps and answers your question!

Cheers

Comment: Looks like you always create a new account on each worker.   Is that correct?  If so, that means you move the eth generated from each account/worker to coinbase at a later time. Is that also a correct assumption?

Answer (score 11):

> Is that correct?

Yes, that's correct. But...

...I think you're conflating two ideas here.

[coinbase.com](https://www.coinbase.com/) is a trading/exchange site, which relatively recently added ETH to the currencies it sells.

A coinbase *account* - which Ethereum also calls the etherbase - is by default the primary *local* account. This can, however, be set to any address you wish - it doesn't have to be an account you created on your local machine.

References:

- [What is Coinbase?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/what-is-coinbase)
- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining
- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts

Comment: Right, totally forgot to take a coinbase.com account into my answer. Thanks for pointing this out here!

Comment: Should you always have a local account for each worker?

Comment: If there isn't a local etherbase account already set up, or if you haven't specified an account (local or otherwise) in the command you use to start the miner, it won't start. Have a look at the instructions at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining

Comment: In case it's not clear: Yes, you can create a local etherbase (coinbase) account before you start mining, or you can specify an account/address which you haven't created on your machine, like you specified in your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a constant coinbase among all nodes, you can simply set the etherbase manually as follows:

```
miner.setEtherbase('0xa4d8e9cae4d04b093aac82e6cd355b6b963fb7ff');
```

AFAIK, you don't even need to have a keystore file, i.e. the specified account does not need to be in `eth.accounts`, but I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. Etherbase is the "target" account for where to put the reward from mining.

It's a [miner setting](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options):

```
MINER OPTIONS:
  --mine                    Enable mining
  --minerthreads value      Number of CPU threads to use for mining (default: 8)
  --etherbase value         Public address for block mining rewards (default = first account created) (default: "0")
  --targetgaslimit value    Target gas limit sets the artificial target gas floor for the blocks to mine (default: 4712388)
  --gasprice "18000000000"  Minimal gas price to accept for mining a transactions
  --extradata value         Block extra data set by the miner (default = client version)
```

You can specify it when running Geth like this:

`geth --mine --etherbase 0xa4d8e9cae4d04b093aac82e6cd355b6b963fb7ff --gasprice "1000000000"`

`gasprice` is the minimum price for executing transactions. It's a function of the [load](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Gas-Price-Oracle) on the network.

Comment: It's now `--miner.etherbase`