# Difference between web3.eth.getCoinbase() and web3.eth.getAccounts()[0]

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, accounts, rpc, coinbase

What is the difference between `web3.eth.getCoinbase()` and  `web3.eth.getAccounts()[0]`. In both cases, I always get the value, which is the currently selected account in Metamask.

Note: The question is relative to a public-facing dApp. i.e. UI that uses web3.js & interacts with a user's crypto wallet Metamask. It is not for local blockchain development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`web3.eth.getCoinbase()` returns the account that your mining rewards go to.

`web3.eth.getAccounts()[0]` returns the first account you created (index 0)

Web3.js doesnt expose this API (probably because from an application level , there aren't strong use cases for it ), but it is possible to set your  Coinbase (Etherbase) to any of your accounts using from the geth console

```
miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[n]) //Where n is the index number
```

> ### Update:

- Metamask doesnt support web3.eth.getCoinbase()  as it is a light client

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client

- The current pattern for dealing with accounts in metamask:

  ```
  var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
  var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== account) {
      account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
      updateInterface();
    }
  }, 100);
  ```

you could probably use web3.eth.getAccounts()[] but this will return an array that you still have to parse.

### Example Taken from documentation:

```
web3.eth.accounts
 web3.eth.accounts
// or async
web3.eth.getAccounts(callback(error, result){ ... })
This property is read only and returns a list of accounts the node controls.

Returns
Array - An array of addresses controlled by client.

Example
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;
console.log(accounts); // ["0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1"]
```

> ### References:

- [How do you configure geth to use coinbase?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/how-do-you-configure-geth-to-use-coinbase)
- https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getcoinbase
- https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client
- https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client
- https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethaccounts

Comment: updated question. pls see note.

Answer (score 0):

Those two commands will produce the same result.

`web3.eth.getCoinbase()` is meant to be used to get your primary (first) account.

`web3.eth.getAccounts()` is meant to be used to interact with all of your accounts. You can specify the first account by adding the `[0]`.

In general, if you are dealing with more than just your first account, you will want to use `getAccounts()` and access your first account with `[0]`. However, it is up the the implementer to decide.

Comment: It is possible to configure the coinbase address to be arbitrary. It might be that it is not betweeen the accounts returned by `web3.eth.getAccounts()`.

Comment: updated question.

Comment: web3.eth.getAccounts() always returns only 1 account, the currently selected account, when using web3.js & metamask. So web3.eth.getAccounts()[0] is your only option anyway.

Comment: Also, when the user switches account in metamask, getCoinBase() returns the currently selected account. Hence both seem to be giving the exact same account, i.e. the currently selected account.

Comment: @Vishal metamask doesnt expose `getCoinBase()` and if you that node has only created one account, this is true. I will be reluctant to use that call for the purposes of selecting the user account through metamask.

Comment: If the user has changed his coin base it wouldn’t