# Where does my mined Ethereum go?

Tags: mining, addresses

I have followed all the steps to mine Ethereum and I am currently mining, but where does what I have mined go?

Is it through the address that I was given through Geth?

How do access the mined Ethereum?

Comment: how are you mining? which tool/pool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are mining in ethermine.org you should see your current mined ETH in the search bar. Just write your address and you'll see it.

Although I don't know if you are mining on your own or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're mining with your own rig, any mining rewards - paid in *ether* - get deposited into the coinbase (aka. etherbase) account on your system.

See the following for a thorough description of which account this actually is: [What is coinbase?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/what-is-coinbase)

I believe that if this account hadn't been set up, then you wouldn't have been able to start mining - there would have been an error message.

From the geth console you can run `eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)` to see its current balance.