# Detect if MetaMask was just unlocked

Tags: web3js, metamask

I want to detect if my user unlock their metamask so I can redirect them to the right page as soon as they unlock instead of having them click away from the "your metamask is locked" page. Is that possible?

Comment: Check that [`web3.eth.coinbase`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/what-is-coinbase) is not `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If metamask is unlocked you should be able to call web3.eth.accounts.getAccounts() ( v 1.0.x ) to retrieve node's owned accounts or web3.eth.accounts with a non empty array node's owned account as result.

Answer (score 0):

[metamask experimental feature](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#experimental-api)

```
 const isLocked = !(await ethereum._metamask.isUnlocked());
  if (isLocked) {
     window.location.reload()
  }
  // if not locked execute the rest of the logic
```