# add miner module to geth javascript console

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I started the geth console with `geth.exe attach http://IP:8545` and tried to set the etherbase with `miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])` and then start the miner with `miner.start()`. I got the exception:

```
ReferenceError: 'miner' is not defined
```

Right now I only have this modules: 
[image: Geth console modules]

How can I add the miner module to to my standard connection command shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting mining you must need to set **etherbase** or **coinbase**. To set etherbase / coinbase use the follwing command -

```
miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])
```

If you don't set an etherbase address then you can not start mining.

Refer the following question to understand 
[What is coinbase?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/what-is-coinbase)

Refer the following documentation for more details -

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining

Hope it helps!

Comment: I set the etherbase but i forgot to mention it in the question. My question is more on how can I add the miner module in the geth javscript console with my standard connection command: geth attach ip:8545?