# are deployed address of an ERC20 smart contract and its token coinbase address the same?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

When an ERC20 smart contract (for example, @openZeppelin [ERC20 contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol)) is deployed to ethereum network, there will be a `deployedAddress` of contract returned.  Meanwhile the token is minted after deployment with a `coinbaseAddress`. Are the `deployedAddress` of the contract and `coinbaseAddress` of token the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenZeppelin ERC20 implementation defines the `mint` function as follow :

```
    /** @dev Creates `amount` tokens and assigns them to `account`, increasing
 * the total supply.
 *
 * Emits a {Transfer} event with `from` set to the zero address.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
 */
function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
    require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");

    _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);

    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
    _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
}
```

When called, this method sets `_totalSupply` and the address `account` receives the minted amount. `account` can be any address except the zero address. The `Transfer` event mentions the zero address as the `from` parameter but this is purely conventional.

There is no such thing of `coinbaseAddress`([What is coinbase?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/what-is-coinbase)). The new coins are programmatically created by the smart contract.

Note that you can implement more complex supply mechanisms (see here for more info : https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc20-supply).

Comment: The coinbase address is the address which receives all initial token supply in the post. This may not be the right way to use `coinbase`. It seems that the ERC20 contract deployment address and the address which receives all coin supply are not the same. BTW the link is for previous version of 2.x. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: `It seems that the ERC20 contract deployment address and the address which receives all coin supply are not the same` : The address receiving the supply can be any address, except the zero address. It could possibly  be the ERC20 contract address if `_mint` is called with `address(this)` for the `account` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the link to match version 3.x.